# How to convert a list of different-sized tensors to a single tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I want to convert a list of tensors with different sizes to a single tensor.

I tried `torch.stack`, but it shows an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-237-76c3ff6f157f> in <module>
----> 1 torch.stack(t)

RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Got 5 and 6 in dimension 1 at C:\w\1\s\tmp_conda_3.7_105232\conda\conda-bld\pytorch_1579085620499\work\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensor.cpp:612
```

My list of tensors:

```
[tensor([-0.1873, -0.6180, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.3607]),
 tensor([-0.6873, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.9768, -0.7590, -0.6707]),
 tensor([-0.6686, -0.7022, -0.7436, -0.8231, -0.6348, -0.4040, -0.6074, -0.6921])]
```

I have also tried this in a different way, instead of tensors, I used a lists of these individual tensors and tried to make a tensor out of it. That also showed an error.

```
list: [[-0.18729999661445618, -0.6179999709129333, -0.3917999863624573, -0.5849000215530396, -0.36070001125335693], [-0.6873000264167786, -0.3917999863624573, -0.5849000215530396, -0.9768000245094299, -0.7590000033378601, -0.6707000136375427], [-0.6686000227928162, -0.7021999955177307, -0.7436000108718872, -0.8230999708175659, -0.6348000168800354, -0.40400001406669617, -0.6074000000953674, -0.6920999884605408]]
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-245-489aea87f307> in <module>
----> 1 torch.FloatTensor(t)

ValueError: expected sequence of length 5 at dim 1 (got 6)
```

Apparently, it says, it is expecting the same length of lists if I am not wrong.

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @helloswift123, you cannot stack tensors of different lengths.

Also, @helloswift123's answer will work only when the total number of elements is divisible by the shape that you want. In this case, the total number of elements is `19` and in no case, it can be reshaped into something useful since it is a prime number.

`torch.cat()` as suggested,

```
data = [torch.tensor([-0.1873, -0.6180, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.3607]),
                torch.tensor([-0.6873, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.9768, -0.7590, -0.6707]),
                torch.tensor([-0.6686, -0.7022, -0.7436, -0.8231, -0.6348, -0.4040, -0.6074, -0.6921])]
dataTensor = torch.cat(data)
dataTensor.numel()
```

Output:

```
tensor([-0.1873, -0.6180, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.3607, -0.6873, -0.3918, -0.5849,
        -0.9768, -0.7590, -0.6707, -0.6686, -0.7022, -0.7436, -0.8231, -0.6348,
        -0.4040, -0.6074, -0.6921])
19
```

Possible solution:

This is also not a perfect solution but might solve this problem.

```
# Have a list of tensors (which can be of different lengths) 
data = [torch.tensor([-0.1873, -0.6180, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.3607]),
        torch.tensor([-0.6873, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.9768, -0.7590, -0.6707]),
        torch.tensor([-0.6686, -0.7022, -0.7436, -0.8231, -0.6348, -0.4040, -0.6074, -0.6921])]

# Determine maximum length
max_len = max([x.squeeze().numel() for x in data])

# pad all tensors to have same length
data = [torch.nn.functional.pad(x, pad=(0, max_len - x.numel()), mode='constant', value=0) for x in data]

# stack them
data = torch.stack(data)

print(data)
print(data.shape)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[-0.1873, -0.6180, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.3607,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [-0.6873, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.9768, -0.7590, -0.6707,  0.0000,  0.0000],
        [-0.6686, -0.7022, -0.7436, -0.8231, -0.6348, -0.4040, -0.6074, -0.6921]])
torch.Size([3, 8])
```

This will append zeros to the end of any tensor which is having fewer elements and in this case you can use `torch.stack()` as usual.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, use `torch.nn.utils.rnn.pad_sequence`

```py
# data = [tensor([1, 2, 3]), 
#         tensor([4, 5])]
data = pad_sequence(data, batch_first=True)
# data = tensor([[1, 2, 3],
#                [4, 5, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>>data = [tensor([-0.1873, -0.6180, -0.3918, -0.5849, -0.3607]),tensor([-0.6873, -0.3918, 
-0.5849, -0.9768, -0.7590, -0.6707]),tensor([-0.6686, -0.7022, -0.7436, -0.8231, 
-0.6348, -0.4040, -0.6074, -0.6921])]

>>>dataTensor = torch.cat(data).reshape(x,y)  #x*y = data.numel()

>>>print(type(dataTensor))
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

`torch.stack` concatenates a sequence of tensors with **same size**.

`torch.cat` concatenates a sequence of tensors.

From the documentation of [`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html):

> Concatenates the given sequence of seq tensors in the given dimension. All tensors must either have the same shape (**except in the concatenating dimension**) or be empty.

Comment: Thank you. this is helpful too.